# JQuery: How to display an array of paragraph tags one by one on each click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var sentences = ['sentenceone', 'another sentence', 'another sentence again'];

$(".btn").on('click', function() {

    for(var i=0; i < sentences.length; i++) {
        samplebox.innerHTML += '<p>'+sentences[i]+'</p>';
    }
});
```

This displays all of them in one click. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can displays the paragraphs one by one like this :

```
var sentences = ['sentenceone', 'another sentence', 'another sentence again'];
var i = 0;

$(".btn").on('click', function() {

  if (i < sentences.length) {
    samplebox.innerHTML += '<p>' + sentences[i] + '</p>';
    i++;
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<button class="btn" data-step="1">Click here</button>

var sentences = ['sentenceone', 'another sentence', 'another sentence again'];

$(".btn").on('click', function() {
        var limit = parseInt( $(this).attr("data-step") ) - 1;
        for(var i=0; i < limit; i++) {
            samplebox.innerHTML += '<p>'+sentences[i]+'</p>';
        }
        $(this).attr("data-step") = limit + 2;
    });
```